# Use case of typename keyword in c++

Tags: c++, templates, iterator, typename

I am wondering why we need to had the **typename** keyword or not in these two situations :

```
template <T>
void foo(void)
{
   std::vector<T> v;
   typename std::vector<T>::iterator it;
}
```

In the case of an iterator the compiler send us an error if typename is not specified.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ 17 Standard (17.7 Name resolution)

> 2 A name used in a template declaration or definition and that is
> dependent on a template-parameter is assumed not to name a type unless
> the applicable name lookup finds a type name or the name is qualified
> by the keyword typename.